# Generate WordPress Theme from GitHub Repository

Tags: repository, github

How do I generate a WordPress theme based on my GitHub repository?

http://underscores.me is what I want to replicate.

Here is a link to the GitHub repot: https://github.com/Automattic/_s

I wish to use my own "foundation" theme.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already detailed here..

https://github.com/Automattic/_s#getting-started

Unless you want something else. :)

Basically once you have a starter Underscores theme, it's all a matter of editing the template files to get it to look the way you want it to.

Comment: I'm looking to "replicate" what you can generate on the http://underscores.me website - thanks for your input. I have my own foundation theme that I wish to generate from my GitHub repo.

Comment: Oh. The _s is just a barebones starter theme. That is what you will get from the site or from their github. You need to manually write the css to replicate the look you want. When you mean generate from your github repo, do you mean you already have a foundation theme there?